# How to enable field in Acumatica - Sales Order with "shipping" status?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need custom field that I added to Sales Order screen to be always enabled even order has been shipped, order having "Shipping" status.
I have extended SOOrder_RowSelected method to enable the custom field but the field is still disabled when the order is in "Shipping" status.

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
    {
        SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;
        if (row == null)
            return;

        if (del != null)
            del(cache, e);

       PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOOrderExt.usrContact>(cache, null, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit broad. Provide some more background perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead of `public virtual void` use `protected virtual void` . Also check weather `del` execution doesn't generate exception ( sometime in my life I was in this situation ).

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
    {
        SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;
        if (row == null)
            return;

        try{
        if (del != null)
            del(cache, e);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 
             //check for surprises
        }

       PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOOrderExt.usrContact>(cache, null, true);
    }
```

Another area of interests can be checking maybe you or somebody else modified it's enabling/disabling via automation steps

Comment: Thank you for your advise.  It was disabled by automation steps.  Therefore, I add the field that I need to enable into respective automation steps, that field become enable.

Comment: I am having a similar case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487060/unable-to-enable-a-custom-field-in-cases?noredirect=1#comment119321216_67487060 in 2020 R1 but couldn't find it being disabled into Automation steps too. Is there any other solution to this?